# Difference between below paths?

Tags: java, spring

I have below paths configured in properties file.

```
C:/folder/file.xml
file:/folder/file.xml
```

one of the above two paths i refer in my spring application context file. My question is what is the `difference between these two paths`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

On Windows both points to the same directory. On *nix based systems the first won't work. So the second is more universal and should be used instead the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Using the relative path is always the better practice. It makes the code more usable as the relative folder structure of the application does not change, not matter which platform or Computer you are using. But it works only when the relative path is correct, unlike the Absolute path which works as long as the path is correct.

Answer (score 1):

`C:/folder/file.xml` is a fully qualified file name
`file:/folder/file.xml` is a URI and it should be `file:///` for local files not `file:/` `file://` is used when accessing network file URIs

URI is not just a Java thing. `file://` means that the resource is a file as opposed to a HTTP resource etc.

Comment: "URI is not just a Java thing" neither is a "fully qualified file name"

Comment: Certainly but I was only emphasizing the URI.

Comment: @Thihara, Thanks for your reply. i am clear now..if file://folder/file.xml is specified, where does spring looks for the file? i mean which folder in the system?

Comment: C:\folder.. And please note the edit. When accessing file in local computer its three slashes. I have put two before by mistake. Two slashes are for network URIs.

Comment: Oh an you can simple experiment using a browser... Just type in `file:///` urls and see where it takes you.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. as i am not specifying drive name how does spring looks exactly in C:\folder ? Please help me..

Comment: It's the root path in windows... In linux it leads to `/` which is file system root, So I am only assuming of course but it should be `C:\`. You can just try with IE.

Answer (score 0):

The file prefix lets spring know that is looking for a file as opposed to a classpath resource, http or ftp resource.

> The UrlResource wraps a java.net.URL, and may be used to access any
>   object that is normally accessible via a URL, such as files, an HTTP
>   target, an FTP target, etc. All URLs have a standardized String
>   representation, such that appropriate standardized prefixes are used
>   to indicate one URL type from another. This includes file: for
>   accessing filesystem paths, http: for accessing resources via the HTTP
>   protocol, ftp: for accessing resources via FTP, etc.